# Determine how many children in a div

Tags: php

Is it possible to define how many children in an element with PHP?

Doing the same as with JQuery:

```
$($element).children().length;
```

Comment: If you're using `DOMNode`, you can count the number of children `$element` has with `$element->childNodes->length;`.

Comment: Just the usual info, in case you didn't know: PHP is server sided and runs on the server (and is *usually* completely obnoxious to what you output - to PHP you're just outputting a series of characters). Javascript is client sided and runs on the client.

Comment: technically you can get the content of output buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP to render the document then you can use something like [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/). If not, then you cannot.

This is because PHP is executed before the HTML is rendered, so there is no way to access the DOM via PHP.